# IONIC | Login Authentication using Active Directory

Tags: ionic-framework

Is it possible to use authenticate user from mobile application using Active Directory credentials in IONIC? I have gone through many google, but could not find any thing specific to Active Directory.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, please consider accepting it, in addition to the upvote. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic Framework is a front end framework. You can authenticate by any means that's available from your backend API.

auth0.com offers a soultion that might work for your needs if you want to integrate against a pre-baked solution rather that writing your own. They have a library for Ionic Framework.

You can find github repo here: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples

Auth0 offers identity management as a service (authentication). The Ionic Framework library claims that you can integrate against:

- Google,
- Facebook,
- Microsoft Account,
- LinkedIn,
- GitHub,
- Twitter,
- Box,
- Salesforce,
- Windows Azure AD,
- Google Apps,
- **Active Directory**,
- ADFS
- or any SAML Identity Provider

Keep in mind that your Active Directory server will have to be available to Auth0 in some way in order for the integration to work. This may not be appropriate if you're building a purely internal enterprise app.

Comment: Hi @jpoveda, the github link mentioned in your comment doesnt exist anymore. New URL: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples

Comment: Updated. Thanks @AshishGoyal